# Meaning of " he is welcome to attend and take part"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am helping my son with an application for an after-school program. I asked the coach if they would still accept new students. The coach emailed me back:

> While we have selected the kids who are moving on in the competition
>   he is welcome to attend and take part.

I am confused. Is this a "yes" or "no"?

Comment: It's a qualified "yes":  Yes, he can show up and do stuff.  However, there is some sort of a competition associated with this program, and he will not be partaking in the competition.  (If this is a chess club, for example, he can show up and learn chess / play matches, but he won't be going to any tournaments.)

Comment: Also, welcome!  Please take the site [tour] and review our [help] section.  If you are not a native English speaker, please consider checking out our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It sounds like this group has some sort of primary core membership, but also has several secondary/ alternate/ practice squad members.  The coach is saying your son can join, but he will be one of the secondary members, and his chance to be a primary member for this year has lapsed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "yes, your child can physically attend" answer.  There are aspects of the program that involve a competition, and the deadline has passed for being a full participant in the competition portion.

If the competition portion of the activity is of concern to your child, e.g., feeling excluded from the group, then you should wait until the next time the program is offered.

In any case, you should contact the coach/activity leader and clarify what the competition is, and what the "exclusion" impact would be on your son, should he choose to participate.